# Invalid Audience Id - Office 365

Tags: office-365, rest

I am trying to connect with office 365 without going through Azure, so I was able to get the access token by calling the following URL

```
https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/myDomain.onmicrosoft.com/tokens/OAuth/2
Parameters:
**resource** 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/myDomain-my.sharepoint.com@myDomain.onmicrosoft.com
**client_id** ab15d15a-9bf6-4f52-b67a-6528398d2ca9@myDomain.onmicrosoft.com
**client_secret** xxxxxxx
**code** xxxxxx
**grant_type** authorization_code
```

But the problem is when I try to call the Office 365 API like this:

> https://myDomain-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/files/getByPath('Shared%20with%20Everyone')/children

I got the following error:

> Invalid audience Uri
>   '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/myDomain.sharepoint.com@132436d6-76fe-4a35-95b5-c2a643463cb4'.

Any hints of what is happening?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2014/03/20/document-libraries-faq.aspx

Comment: Hi! I am not using visual studio or .net, I could not understand  how to solve this error. Can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: do you know any other documentations that might help?